# Does Path Object have builtin method to test if directory is in the Path

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

Is there a way to check if a directory is in the path of a python `Path` object. I know I can test it by converting it to a string like `'dir' in str(Path('/dir/dir2/dir3'))` or `'dir' in Path('/dir/dir2/dir3').parts` but I'm hoping there is a built in method. I've checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) but didn't see anything that is a builtin method that would do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
p=Path('/dir/dir2/dir3')
if p.match("*dir*"):
    print("found 'dir' in path")
```

This should find if `dir` is anywhere in the given path.

Comment: Was hoping wouldn't have to use globs but this does answer the question of using a built in method so accepted

Comment: @MatthewBarlowe I think without globs, your best bet is still your 2nd option of splitting the path with `parts` and seeing if `dir` is in that tuple.